# integration tests - embedded jetty - how to setup data

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, embedded-jetty

I wonder how do you usually setup data for integration tests.

When my tests begin I start embedded jetty:

```
@Before
public void startServer() throws Exception {
    server = new Server(8080);
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setDescriptor("WEB-INF/embedded-web.xml");
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/core-test");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");  
    webAppContext.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    server.addHandler(webAppContext);
    server.start();
}
```

In embedded-web.xml there is a reference to spring application context:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In applicationContext-test.xml there is a configuration for in memory h2 database:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
</bean>
```

The best solution would be to autowire Spring service classes into tests and then setup database, but I guess it's impossible to access application context started by jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are 3 solutions to provide data to integration tests:

1. Use spring application listener that is being run when application context starts

   ```
   public class CustomTestInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
       @Autowired
       CustomService customService;

       @Override
       public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
         // TODO: implement you loginc
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can provide sql import files while configuring entity manager (it-test-init.sql is located in src/test/resouces):

   ```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="jpaProperties">
           <props>
               <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">it-test-init.sql</prop>
           </props>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```
3. You can use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) and execute test on the remote server (e.g. JBoss). It is highly recommended when you use Java EE/container technologies that are difficult to run on the embedded server (CDI, EJB, etc.).